# Unknown function behavior

Tags: javascript, html, logic

I'm trying to understand what this function do, but I'm clueless. Any ideas?

```
var mystery = function (str) {
    var x=true;
    for(var i=0; i<str.length/2; i++){
        if(str.charAt(i)!=str.charAt(str.length-i-1)){
            x = false;
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: +1, cool palindrome function. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It simply tests if the string is symmetric, that is has every character at index `i` equal to the character at the same distance from end of string (at `length-i-1`) like `"radar"`.

It could be simplified and made faster like this :

```
var mystery = function (str) {
    for (var i=0; i<str.length/2; i++){
        if (str.charAt(i) !== str.charAt(str.length-i-1)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And a little faster but less clear :

```
var mystery = function (str) {
    for (var i=~~(str.length/2); i--;){
        if (str.charAt(i) !== str.charAt(str.length-i-1)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

For the fun, the jspef confirming it : http://jsperf.com/palyndromes